# internet connection tester script

Tags: linux

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=rykHdvBh

bix.hu and www.yahoo.com are "pingable" test sites.
127.0.0.1 could not be pinged [firewall drops all icmp]

i have a "oneliner" that echoes if theres "internet connection or no".
`$ ping -W 1 -c 2 bix.hu >& /dev/null && ping -W 1 -c 2 www.yahoo.com >& /dev/null && echo "internet connection ok" || echo "no internet connection"`
`internet connection ok`
`$ ping -W 1 -c 2 127.0.0.1 >& /dev/null && ping -W 1 -c 2 www.yahoo.com >& /dev/null && echo "internet connection ok" || echo "no internet connection"`
`no internet connection`
`$ ping -W 1 -c 2 127.0.0.1 >& /dev/null && ping -W 1 -c 2 127.0.0.1 >& /dev/null && echo "internet connection ok" || echo "no internet connection"`
`no internet connection`
`$ ping -W 1 -c 2 bix.hu >& /dev/null && ping -W 1 -c 2 127.0.0.1 >& /dev/null && echo "internet connection ok" || echo "no internet connection"`
`no internet connection`
`$ ping -W 1 -c 2 bix.hu >& /dev/null && ping -W 1 -c 2 www.yahoo.com >& /dev/null && echo "internet connection ok" || echo "no internet connection"`
`internet connection ok`
`$`

Ok!

But: if i want the "oneliner" to only go along when theres internet connection:
`$ while $TORF; do ping -W 1 -c 1 bix.hu >& /dev/null && ping -W 1 -c 1 www.yahoo.com >& /dev/null && TORF=false || TORF=true; done`
`$ while $TORF; do ping -W 1 -c 1 127.0.0.1 >& /dev/null && ping -W 1 -c 1 www.yahoo.com >& /dev/null && TORF=false || TORF=true; done`
`$ while $TORF; do ping -W 1 -c 1 127.0.0.1 >& /dev/null && ping -W 1 -c 1 127.0.0.1 >& /dev/null && TORF=false || TORF=true; done`
`$ while $TORF; do ping -W 1 -c 1 bix.hu >& /dev/null && ping -W 1 -c 1 127.0.0.1 >& /dev/null && TORF=false || TORF=true; done`
`$ while $TORF; do ping -W 1 -c 1 bix.hu >& /dev/null && ping -W 1 -c 1 www.yahoo.com >& /dev/null && TORF=false || TORF=true; done`
`$` 

It just doesn't work. 

Goal: if theres no internet connection, then the oneliner must loop until there is internet connection. if theres internet connection the oneliner ends.

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting TORF variable works in a subshell and is not passed to current shell. You can try something without variable:

```
while true; do ping -W 1 -c 1 bix.hu >/dev/null && ping -W 1 -c 1 www.yahoo.com >/dev/null && continue; break; done
```

To wait until there is Internet connection (at least one site responds):

```
while true; do (ping -W 1 -c 1 bix.hu >/dev/null || ping -W 1 -c 1 www.yahoo.com >/dev/null) && break; done
```